# How to group and limit outcomes data

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've the following query running on ms-access :

```
select
t1.[supplier code], t1.date1,t1.date2
from
otifdatatoexport t1 left join otifdatatoexport t2 on 
t1.date1 >= t1.date2 and t1.[supplier code] = t2.[supplier code]
group by
t1.date1,
t1.[supplier code],t1.date2
order by
t1.[supplier code],
t1.date1
```

[image]

Thing is I would like to keep only 3 records (**not less not more**, see picture red frame) when outputting for the couple t1.[supplier code], t1.date1. Is there a way to achieve this?

Here attached the table data and the outcomes:
[image]

Comment: Can you show the original data and explain what you want the query to do?  Your query seems to have nothing to do with table2, so the logic is really unclear.

Comment: Hello Gordon, I've attached the original data. The query output data that and I would like like only and if only I have three rows in the row as shown in the first picture

Comment: At least I have no idea what you are trying to accomplish, neither conceptual, nor datawise. Could you rephrase the rules and what the magic about the three records are, please?

Comment: Hello, I attched a picture with the table data and outcomes. I put in color to explain the logoc. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the most recent three rows for each supplier, you can use `in`:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.date in (select top (3) t2.date
                 from t t2
                 where t2.supplier = t.supplier
                 order by t2.date desc
                );
```

This is based on the edit to your question.  You only show one table of data, so I don't know why your query is referring to multiple tables.